# .offset() and checking the position in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is my HTML code:

```
<div class="snake">
        <div class="body"></div>
    </div>
```

In script I have a function that creates body parts and appends them to `.snake`.

It looks something like this:

```
$('.btn1').click(function() {
    length++;
    $('<div></div>').addClass('body').appendTo('.snake').css('left', xPos * length * 1.2 + '%');   
});
```

Then another function removes the last body part, creates a new one, puts it on the top and gives it `.head` class.

```
$('.snake').children().last().remove();
$('<div></div>').addClass('body').prependTo('.snake').css('top', 0 + '%').css('left', xPos * blocks_moved * 1.2 + '%');
$('.snake').children().removeClass('head');
$('.snake').children().first().addClass('head');
```

So every time this function is called new `<div>` is given the `.head` class.

```
var headPos = $('.head').offset();
            alert(headPos);
```

In the two lines of code above I tried to alert `.head`'s position but I used `.offset()` so it should alert coordinates depending on document not on parent element. This two lines are also in teh function above. It alerts something like [object Object]. Why isn't this working? I need this variable so I can set `.snake` position the same as `.head` position.

I tried this with `$('.snake').position(headPos);` but I think that `.position()` function can't set the position. Any other ways of doing this and some help with `.offset()` would be great. I'm new to programming so any advices would be helpful. :)

P.S.

I forgot one more thing. What about css? Which position values should I use? I used `position: absolute;` with both head and body parts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`offset()` is an object containing two properties, `top` and `left`.

use `offset().top` to get the y position

```
var headPos_x = $('.head').offset().left;
var headPos_y = $('.head').offset().top;
alert("x:" + headPos_x + ", y:" + headPos_y);
```